# How to filter in pandas based on string value?

Tags: pandas, csv

I want to filter a pandas dataframe based on the id of the row. The id is a sequence of patient names. For example, I have columns in this format:

```
 ID | A | B
```

And the id values looks like `TCGA-A6-6653-01Z-00-DX1.e130666d-2681-4382-9e7a-4a4d27cb77a4` but multiple repeating ones. I want to group the unique ids and do a mean operation on A and B.

Can anyone guide me?  
 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can just groupby id and do mean for the remaining columns.

```
df.groupby('id').mean()
```